# MySQL Query doesn't seem to be outputting expectations

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me here please.  Unless I'm missing the blindingly obvious, i'm total stumped.

How is this query returning that line, when I'm asking for everything less or equal to 6 in the price column, and every greater or equal to 500 in the minutes column.

1. minutes is a varchar
2. price is an int

price is an int

[image: To put it briefly, what is going on here]

```
CREATE TABLE `gg_Crates` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `minutes` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `sms` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `data` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `bb` int(5) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Please add to your question the result from `show create table gg_Crates`

Comment: Why is minutes of type varchar and not int?

Comment: I needed to add an unlimited value which i set as 'unlim'

Comment: Use a nullable int column and use null for unlimited ? Magic values in a varchar field meant to store ints can only lead to problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that row because you are comparing strings. `"500" >= "60"` is true, because of ASCII characters order.

You have to change the type of the `minutes` column or parse the value when filtering data. Eg.

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(minutes,UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS minutes_int
...
WHERE
...
AND `minutes_int` >= 600
...
```

As could also try comparing the string value to the integer value directly, eg.

```
AND `minutes` >= 600
```

by removing the commas, but I suggest you to think about changing the column format, if possible, since representing minutes as a `varchar(11)` is not correct and will also make you occupy lots of space without reason.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, numbers shouldn't be quoted in your query.  It looks quoting `500` is causing mysql to do a string comparison between `"500"` and `minutes, instead of a numeric comparison.

Get rid of quotes around the numbers and it'll work as expected.

Comment: No it won't as minutes is of type varchar which should've been int (or any other numeric type).

Comment: @Robill - I didn't notice that he had his minutes field as a varchar.  However, my answer is still actually correct - if he had entered his numbers as numbers, mysql would have done an implicit cast of varchar => int.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two strings and expecting a number comparison output. In other words, you want to do `500 >= 60` but you actually run `"500" >= "60"` which means `STRCMP("500", "60")`, which doesn't have the same result.

Cast your column as integer and make your comparison using numbers instead.

`WHERE CONVERT(minutes, UNSIGNED INTEGER) >= 500`

Answer (score -1):

Try using brackets `( )` in the conditions. Similar issue happened with me too.
Sometimes, the engine doesn't capture the `AND` operator when brackets aren't used.

Comment: No it doesn't. The problem is with K20GH comparing strings, not numbers.