# Mysql string and number not equal/matched

Tags: mysql, sql, search, string-comparison

I've been trying to write a simple keyword comparison query in mysql but for some reason an all numeric keyword won't match an all numeric search term.

I have a table of products, a table of keywords and joining table. To make things simpler I'm using a view which performs the join, giving me a simple list of keyword strings per product id. 1 product in particular has 4 keywords, "John", "Deere", "8000", "Midroller" and these show up correctly in the view and when joined.

Where I am having trouble is that (keyword = "8000") is never true for the "8000" keyword.

**Example**

```
SELECT a.id, kw.keyword AS keyword, (kw.keyword = 'John' OR 
  kw.keyword = 'Deere' OR 
  kw.keyword = "8000" OR 
  kw.keyword = 'Midroller') AS matched
FROM `kc5n2_product` AS a
INNER JOIN `product_keywords` AS kw ON a.id = kw.product
WHERE a.id =119
```

returns

```
 id    keyword    matches
119    8000       0
119    John       1
119    Deere      1
119    Midroller  1
```

I've had a look at this:
[MySql: Compare 2 strings which are numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749219/mysql-compare-2-strings-which-are-numbers)
but it didn't really help.

I also found this [MySQL Query doesn't seem to be outputting expectations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619340/mysql-query-doesnt-seem-to-be-outputting-expectations/16619391#16619391) but I'm trying trying to compare them as strings, not as numbers.

Even trying

```
SELECT a.id, kw.keyword AS keyword, (CAST(kw.keyword as Char(4)) = CAST("8000" as Char(4))) AS matched
```

to try to force mysql to interpret them both as strings didn't help at all.

I found that it will match the search term if I use

```
kw.keyword LIKE "%8000%"
```

but I'd prefer to avoid LIKE if I can as at this stage I would like to keep the search fairly restrictive.

Is there something obvious I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you may have leading/trailing spaces in a row containing `8000`

Comment: Exactly right! The extra spaces didn't show up in phpmyadmin so I didn't even think to check it. It's a bit frustrating that it was something so basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like this it usually means that your "misbehaving" value has leading/trailing spaces in  it.

You can find all these "bad" records with a query like this

```
SELECT *
  FROM keywords
 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(keyword) <> CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(keyword))
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3830/2)** demo

And you can obviously fix them with a simple update like this

```
UPDATE keywords
   SET keyword = TRIM(keyword)
 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(keyword) <> CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(keyword))
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/977e6/1)** demo

Comment: With select CHAR_LENGTH(files.name) FROM files where id=56 or id=55;
I get 23 and 22.  the first one has a trailing space.  But when I try your search with <> nothing returns,  Same if I use !=.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in what you have posted. I setup a test case:

```
CREATE TABLE product (id INT);
CREATE TABLE product_keywords (product INT, keyword VARCHAR(32));

INSERT INTO product
  VALUES (19),(20);
INSERT INTO product_keywords 
  VALUES (19,'Foo'),(19,'John'),(19,'Deere'),(19,'8000'),(19,'Midroller');

SELECT a.id
     , kw.keyword AS keyword
     , ( kw.keyword = 'John' OR 
         kw.keyword = 'Deere' OR 
         kw.keyword = "8000" OR 
         kw.keyword = 'Midroller'
       ) AS matched
  FROM `product` a 
  JOIN `product_keywords` kw 
    ON a.id = kw.product
 WHERE a.id = 19

    id  keyword    matched  
------  ---------  -------
    19  Foo              0
    19  John             1
    19  Deere            1
    19  8000             1
    19  Midroller        1
```

it looks good to me. (I'd use single quotes around the 8000 literal rather than double quotes, but in default MySQL configuration, it doesn't make a difference.)

Perhaps its a problem in your view query.

What does this query return?

```
SELECT kw.* FROM product_keywords kw WHERE kw.product = 119 ORDER BY kw.keyword ;
```

Comment: It returns the all four keywords properly. @peterm figured it out, I'm a bit annoyed it was something so simple.